# PySpark dataframe transformation - to get value part from JSON

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I have a dataframe like below in which it has both key and value pairs.

```text
| Name |  Age | Location
| abc  |  12  | loc1
| def  |  13  | loc2
```

I wanted to create a json string out of it. When I do a `.toJSON()` and collect I am getting the below json string from that dataframe

```json
[{"name":"abc","age":12,"location":"loc1"},{"name":"def","age":13,"location":"loc2"}]
```

Is it possible to just get the value part of json instead of getting keys like below ?

Expected output:

```
[{"abc",12,"loc1"},{"def",13,"loc2"}]
```

Code I am using to convert dataframe to json

```
df.toJSON().collect()
```

It would be great if we can get some solutions in PYSPARK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you expect is not a valid JSON, so you can't use `toJSON()` on dataframe or `to_json` function.

You can try something like this using `format_string` function to get the structure you want:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

result = df.groupBy().agg(
    F.collect_list(
        F.format_string('{"%s", %s, "%s"}', *df.columns)
    ).alias("records")
).first()["records"]

print(result)
# ['{"abc", 12, "loc1"}', '{"def", 13, "loc2"}']
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If we have a proper json something like below - [[def,13,14],[12,13,14]]. How can we do that in pyspark ?

Comment: @act_coder still this is not a proper json, you can check it yourself using some json lint. but to get array of arrays you can change the part `F.format_string('{"%s", %s, "%s"}', *df.columns)` into `F.array(*df.columns)` in the above code.

Comment: when i convert to array[array] using F.array function - i am not able to preserve the datatype. Everything is coming with single quotes like this - [['abc','12','loc1'],['abc','12','loc1']]. Is it possible to preserve the data type as well when we convert to Arrays ?

Comment: @act_coder no, all array elements must have the same type. You can't have integers and string that's why everything is converted to string by spark.